# Which Compact Views is correct to use directly?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx

In some view like [AppCompatTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatTextView?hl=en) we can read

> This will automatically be used when you use EditText in your layouts
>   and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You
>   should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

But sometime not, like [LinearLayoutCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/LinearLayoutCompat?hl=en)

So this means that we should use LinearLayoutCompat directly instead of LinearLayout ?

In case, which Compact Views is correct to use directly?

Answer (score -1):

> So this means that we should use LinearLayoutCompat directly instead
>   of LinearLayout ?

The answer is Yes.

> which Compact Views is correct to use directly?

You should be able to use all the Compat views directly without any issue. AFAIK...They are built to provide more compatibility and they tend to be updated more frequently as almost all of them come from Support or AndroidX libraries which receive more frequent updates.

Comment: if the correct pattern is to use all compact, why they are implemented the compiler substitution ?